# Is the error "EventSource failed loading: GET "http://localhost:8016/_next/webpack-hmr?page=/" causing my problem with the Link component in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, routes, react-router, next.js

I am trying to implement this [Menu Item](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/menu/#types-secondary-pointing) with the [Link component](https://nextjs.org/docs#routing) in Next.js.

This my current behavior which is obviously is not desired.

[image]

You can see at some point the `<Link/>` component or perhaps its the `<Menu.Item/>` falls out of sync.

This is how the `<Menu.Item/>` works as per their [docs](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/menu/#types-secondary-pointing).

You can see how snappy it's behaving, but that's with the `<Link/>` tag commented out...

[image]

This is the greater HOC.

```
var comparator;
const GenericIsUserLoggedInLink = React.memo(({ isHomeButton, isLoggedIn, logOutUser, route, anchorText, mobile, name, active, handleItemClick }) => {

 comparator = (prevProps, nextProps) => {

  if (prevProps.isHomeButton !== nextProps.setProps.isHomeButton) {
   return true;
  }
  if (prevProps.isLoggedIn !== nextProps.setProps.isLoggedIn) {
   return true;
  }
  if (prevProps.mobile !== nextProps.setProps.mobile) {
   return true;
  }
  if (prevProps.name !== nextProps.setProps.name) {
   return true;
  }
  if (prevProps.active !== nextProps.setProps.active) {
   return true;
  }
  return false;
 }

 function currentNav(route, name, active, handleItemClick) {

  return (
   <Link href={route}>
     <Menu.Item
      to={route}
      key={name}
      name={name}
      active={active == name}
      onClick={(e) => handleItemClick(e, { name })}
     >
    </Menu.Item>
    </Link>
  );

 }

 if (isHomeButton) {
  return currentNav(route, name, active, handleItemClick)
 }
 if (isLoggedIn) {
  if (anchorText === undefined) {
   return <Link href="/"><a onClick={() => logOutUser()}>Log out!</a></Link>
  }
  else if (mobile) {
   return currentNav(route, name, active, handleItemClick)
  }
  else if (!(mobile)) {
   return currentNav(route, name, active, handleItemClick)
  }

  else if (anchorText) {
   return <Link href={route}><a>{anchorText}</a></Link>
  }
 } else {
  if (route === "/login") {
   return <Link href="/login"><a>Log in!</a></Link>
  }
  return null
 }
}, comparator);
```

In the Next.js docs they recommend using an Imperative [approach.](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#imperatively)

This is how I implemented it in my case.

The handler function in the class...

```
handleItemClick = (e, { name }) => {
  if (name.includes('home')) name = ''
  Router.push('/' + name); this.setState({ activeItem: name })}
```

And this is how I am using it:

```
function currentNav(route, name, active, handleItemClick) {

 console.log("route ", route);
  return (

    <Menu.Item
     to={name}
     key={name}
     name={name}
     active={active == name}
     onClick={(e) => handleItemClick(e, { name })}
    >
    </Menu.Item>
  );

 }
```

So while trying this approach I noticed this in the console.

`EventSource failed loading: GET "http://localhost:8016/_next/webpack-hmr?page=/".`

Again, the route/page changing is working perfectly, it's just the active state from semantic-ui-react which is not in sync.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever find what was causing that `EventSource failed loading` error?

Comment: Also assuming this is still an issue for you, I noticed you're navigating then storing that in component state with `setState` which may be the cause of the 2 going out of sync (setState being async). Why not just set the active item based on the path like: `const path = window.history.pathname.split("/").filter(p => !!p); const activeItem = path[path.length -1]`